# getting data from Mongoose

Tags: javascript

```js
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db1"
//connect to mangodb 


mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var dbo = db.db("db1");
    var query = { username: "mrkinix" };
    dbo.collection("db1").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      db.close();
    });
});
```

alright first time i use mongoose and when i execute it with node in cmd i get this error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.db is not a function

I want to connect to a Mongoose DB and get data from it!  can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't connecting in the right way. The quickstart guide is here:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

According to the guide, this is how you connect:

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/db1"
//connect to mongodb 

mongoose.connect(url)

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    // we're connected!
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);

    // find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields
    Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
       if (err) return handleError(err);
       // Prints "Space Ghost is a talk show host".
       console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation);
    });

});
```

Note that it looks like there were some big API changes to mongoose from version 4 to version 5. So make sure you're reading the docs for the right version.

Here's the V4 docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html

Here's the V5 docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

I recommend doing the quick start guide for the version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
//require mongoose

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to mongodb

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/homework');
```

learn more here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/index.html